# Salesforce Dynamic IP List

Tags: ip

Does Salesforce have a Dynamic IP List of all of its IPs, and if so, what is the URL to the list? We are looking for an internet-accessible dynamic list that our firewalls can pull from to update its policies.

Comment: you can find salesforce ip's from this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384438&type=1) not sure, if there is an api for that.

Comment: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdbPrUAJ/api-for-ips-to-whitelist